# Auto Saving text from textbox

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

I have a sheet in my workbook that logs the changes to another sheet. It does not log changes to the textbox on the sheet.

I am trying to save the information in the textbox at save.

I tried to use the code I used to log the other changes but the code doesn't work. I don't get any errors, but the text is not being saved in the cell.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim sSheetName As String
    Dim Narrative As Object
    sSheetName = "1107"
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> "LogDetails" Then
        Sheets("LogDetails").Unprotect
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "Narraive Box"
        Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = Sheets("1107").Narrative.Text
        Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = Environ("username")
        Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Now
    
        Sheets("LogDetails").Columns("A:D").AutoFit
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
End Sub
```

The textbox is not an ActiveX textbox, just a regular textbox.

I see now the event was not happening because of the `If ActiveSheet.Name <> "LogDetails" Then`.
When I remove the if statements most of the code works, but it doesn't copy the text from the Narrative textbox.

Current code. Once I get the copying the textbox I'll worry about the triggering event.

```vb
    Dim sSheetName As String
    Dim logSheet As Worksheet
    Dim logRow As Range
    Set logSheet = Sheets("LogDetails")
    Dim Narrative As Object
    sSheetName = "1107"

    logSheet.Unprotect
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "Narrative Box"
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = Sheets("1107").Shapes("Narrative").TextFrame.Characters.Text
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = Environ("username")
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Now
            
    Sheets("LogDetails").Columns("A:D").AutoFit
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  
End Sub
```

My main issue was that I was using script that calls an object instead of a shape. It was confusing to get to the ultimate answer since other issues were also mixed in there at different times. Like it wasn't copying the information because there was no information in the textbox.

Comment: Minor detail, but you spelled "Narrative" wrong on your first `.Value`. line. Also I see where you declare `Narrative`, but where do you assign an object to it?

Comment: Is the event definitely firing?

Comment: Not sure if it does when the whole program runs. When I try to step through I get an error message at the "Narrative Box" line saying that the worksheet is protected but the code should have unprotected it.

Comment: Ok, this last time I stepped through it, the event didn't fire. It's set to fire before a save or am I misunderstanding how the Workbook_BeforeSave works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your TextBox is a classic Shape, you might need to use `Shapes("Narrative").TextFrame.Characters.Text`

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim logSheet as Worksheet
    Dim logRow as Range
    Set logSheet = Sheets("LogDetails")
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> "LogDetails" Then
        logSheet.Unprotect
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Set logRow = Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        logRow.Value = "Narrative Box"
        logRow.Offset(0, 1).Value = Sheets("1107").Shapes("Narrative").TextFrame.Characters.Text
        logRow.Offset(0, 2).Value = Environ("username")
        logRow.Offset(0, 3).Value = Now
        logSheet.Columns("A:D").AutoFit
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I made these changes, but the event isn't firing. When I stop through and I get to a portion of the code that saves the worksheet, it doesn't start this piece of code. Even when I manually save the workbook, this code doesn't seem to run.

Comment: Are events enabled? If code is stopped before `Application.EnableEvents = True` runs, the events might be stucks in an "off" mode

Comment: Just run `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the Immediate windows to be sure.

Comment: The Application.EnableEvents in the code? That didn't work, I get an application-defined or object-defined error. Now when Application.EnableEvents is set to false, I get an error saying the worksheet is protected, even though I set the sheet to unprotect. If I take it out of the Before_Save event and just step through, it works fine.

Comment: If I save manually (not via the macro, but just clicking save) I get an error saying the "item with the specified name wasn't found." on the line copying the text in the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the ActiveX text box?

you could try this one

```
Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1107").TextBox1.Text
```

Comment: I originally had an activeX textbox but it was doing really weird stuff when I tried to set it to resize to accommodate the text. The classic textbox really helped avoid this.